# An infinite set of continuous functions doesn't have to be a set of equally continuous functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been studying about sets of equally bounded functions and equally continuous functions. I've found a question which states: Show an example where an infinite set of continuous functions doesn't necessarily need to be set of equally continuous functions.

If someone can give me a simple example I would appreciate it. I've tried googling it but couldn't find the right term for those sets.

Comment: I suppose you're meaning an equicontinuous set of functions?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set of functions with their derivatives uniformly bounded is  equicontinuous.

A concrete example:
$$\bigl\{f_n\in\mathcal C\bigl([0,+\infty)\bigr)\mid f_n(x)=\sin(x+4n^2\pi^2),\enspace x\in[0,+\infty)\bigr\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "equally continuous" you mean equicontinuous, just consider the set of functions $f_a(x)=ax\ $ $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$